# 0.72.7 react native ios crash in Fatal Exception: NSMallocException, Failed to grow buffer

Tags: react-native, crashlytics

Fatal Exception: NSMallocException - Failed to grow buffer.
Getting this Firebase logs for IOS only not android.
Error logs are given below.

```
Fatal Exception: NSMallocException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x92c80 \__exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x14ee4 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x19174c -\[NSInvocation retainArguments\].cold.1
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18a3a4 \__CFReallocationFailed
4  CoreFoundation                 0x30f9c \__CFSafelyReallocate
5  Foundation                     0x36f24 \_NSMutableDataGrowBytes
6  Foundation                     0x32d50 -\[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:\]
7  Foundation                     0x786b8 \__49-\[\_NSDispatchData enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:\]\_block_invoke
8  Foundation                     0x7abf8 -\[\_NSDispatchData enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:\]
9  Foundation                     0x6101c -\[NSConcreteMutableData appendData:\]
10 CommonApp_myAppName                      0x22bd40 -\[RCTNetworkTask URLRequest:didReceiveData:\] + 168 (RCTNetworkTask.mm:168)
11 CommonApp_myAppName                      0x226764 -\[RCTHTTPRequestHandler URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:\] + 171 (RCTHTTPRequestHandler.mm:171)
12 CFNetwork                      0x606c4 CFHTTPCookieStorageCreateFromFile
13 Foundation                     0x4e39c __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
14 Foundation                     0x5fa70 -\[NSBlockOperation main\]
15 Foundation                     0x39a8c __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__
16 Foundation                     0x49fcc -\[NSOperation start\]
17 Foundation                     0x4d498 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__
18 Foundation                     0x5accc \__NSOQSchedule_f
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x11544 \_dispatch_block_async_invoke2
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x64094 \_dispatch_client_callout
21 libdispatch.dylib              0xa73c \_dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp
22 libdispatch.dylib              0xb1f4 \_dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x14ec8 \_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1e10 \_pthread_wqthread
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x193c start_wqthread
```

React 18.2.0
React native 0.72.7
iPadOS 15.7.1
Model:iPad (6th generation)
Keys: crash_info_entry_0 Failed to allocate %zu bytes, requested = %zu, old size = %zu
RAM free: 29.34 MB
Disk free: 6.32 GB
Orientation:Portrait
Getting crash from firebase console.